# How to post a collection of ids with multiple select form field with phoenix_html

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I’m trying to get multiple select to work with the phoenix_html form helpers

```
<%= select f, :challenge_ids, ["foo": "1","bar": "2","baz": "3"], class: "form-control", multiple: ""  %>
```

but only the id of the last selected item gets sent to the server in the params

```
%{"challenge_ids" => "3", "content" => "", "name" => ""}
```

I have also tried changing `:challeng_ids` to `:"challenge_ids[]"` trying to get something similar to a rails output for a multiple select tag, but this didn't make any difference

Comment: We don't support multiple selects yet. But I believe you know that because you just sent a PR. :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Aaron's [PR for adding multiple_select](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix_html/pull/17) was merged into phoenix_html. Here's an example from the [docs](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_html/Phoenix.HTML.Form.html#multiple_select/4) for `multiple_select/4` in case someone else stumbled across the same problem:

```
# Assuming form contains a User model
multiple_select(form, :roles, ["Admin": 1, "Power User": 2])
#=> <select id="user_roles" name="user[roles][]">
    <option value="1">Admin</option>
    <option value="2">Power User</option>
    </select>
```