# How to Create a Select Tag with Options and Values from a Separate Model in the Phoenix Framework

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I've got a relatively simple form with a select tag (drop down form field).

The options/values for the select tag are dynamic and should be updated when my Categories model is updated.

Here's what I've got now:

The form is rendered through the `web/templates/posts/new.html.eex` template like this:

```
<%= render "form.html", changeset: @changeset,
                        action: project_path(@conn, :create) %>
```

Here's the relevant form field in `web/templates/posts/form.html.eex`

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= select f, :category, MyApp.Category, class: "form-control" %>
    <%= error_tag f, :category %>
  </div>
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
protocol Enumerable not implemented for MyApp.Category
```

How do I use my Categories repository as select tag options in a form?

EDIT: I've fetched the categories in my PostController's new action as suggested by Gazler (thanks Gaz).

```
def new
  categories = Repo.all(MyApp.Category)
  changeset = 
  user
  |> build_assoc(:projects)
  |> Project.changeset()
  render(conn, "new.html", changeset: changeset)
end
```

and updated my template:

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= select f, :category, @categories, class: "form-control" %>
    <%= error_tag f, :category %>
  </div>
```

and now I'm getting the following error:

```
assign @categories not available in eex template.
```

EDIT: It looks like maybe I should be using `multiple_select/4` as [Aaron did here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31373730/how-to-post-a-collection-of-ids-with-multiple-select-form-field-with-phoenix-htm) because I'd like the options to show the category title and the value to be the category ID.

ANSWER:

Ended up using this line from the link that Gazler posted (in my post_controller's new action):

```
categories = Repo.all(Qlc.Category) |> Enum.map(&{&1.title, &1.id})
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to fetch your options (in your controller):

```
def new(conn, params) do
  query = from(c in Category, select: {c.id, c.name})
  categories = Repo.all(query)
  changeset = 
    user
    |> build_assoc(:projects)
    |> Project.changeset()
    render(conn, "new.html", changeset: changeset, categories: categories) 
end
```

Then you should use it in the select. Not the change from `:category` to `:category_id`

```
<div class="form-group">
  <%= select f, :category_id, @categories, class: "form-control" %>
  <%= error_tag f, :category_id %>
</div>
```

You will probably need to transform the options. Please see [How to show all records of a model in Phoenix select field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33805309/how-to-show-all-records-of-a-model-in-phoenix-select-field) for how to do this.

Comment: That gives me this error: `assign @categories not available in eex template`.

Comment: @AndrewHendrie Could you please post your templates?

Comment: edited to include template - it's the same as the one you posted. see edit regarding post_controller's new action as well.

Comment: How are you rendering the template? Are you rendering within another template?

Comment: ahh yes, the form is rendered through the new template (edited answer).

Comment: You need to pass it through assigns to your template. `<%= render "form.html", changeset: @changeset, categories: @categories`...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109459/discussion-between-andrew-hendrie-and-gazler).